# SqlMembership, get list of roles for specific user

Tags: c#, t-sql, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have a system which has a many-to-many relationship between users and roles. with that in mind, I created a table to accommodate the design, called `RolesOfUser`. it's basically like this:

```
|  User  |   Role   |
|--------|----------|
| user1  |  Maker   |
| user1  | Approver |
| user1  |  Admin   |
| user2  |  Maker   |
| user2  | Approver |
| user3  |  Maker   |
| user3  |  Admin   |
```

The database is set up this way because in the program, **certain features are available only to specific users**, i.e. only Makers can add new records or update existing records, only Approvers can approve or reject records, and only Admins have access to the User Management module. Also, **certain functions like buttons and such are also specific** to certain user types.

How would I be able to fetch the roles using `SqlMembership`, into my C# program? `SqlMembership` doesn't seem have a property, method, or event I can use. they're all "GetUser" etc., I need a "GetRole".

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for GetRolesForUser(UserName)?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getrolesforuser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished using forms authentication in your application. 
Assuming that each module is in its own directory, you could specify user privileges per directory in web.config..

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="MYWEBAPP.ASPXAUTH"
            loginUrl="login.aspx"
            protection="All"
            path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="administrators">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <!-- Order and case are important below -->
            <allow roles="Administrator"/> <!-- Tell it what roll is allowed -->
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="users">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <!-- Order and case are important below -->
            <allow roles="User"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Reference - [Role Based Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2905/Role-based-Security-with-Forms-Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing too many pieces in the puzzle. As the result, your question cannot be answer in a single answer.

First of all,

1. You want to name the table as **UsersInRoles** which is a common name for that table
2. If you create your own Users, Roles and UsersInRoles (RolesOfUser), you cannot use DefaultMembershipProvider. Instead, you need to use Custom Membership Provider and Custom Role Provider. There are a lot of articles in Google about how to implement Custom Providers.
3. Then finally, you can call [RoleProvider's GetRolesForUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getrolesforuser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: so, if I have my own set of users and roles in my database, I have no choice but to implement Custom Membership and Role Providers? I don't mind doing that, just asking.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. We've a lot of day-off over here. Yes, you'll need to implement Custom Membership and Role Providers.